# how to migrate records to specific cells in another excel sheet and append the result

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I give you a clear example. Let's assume we have 4 rows in the input sheet (from rows 2 to 5), then the output should look like this in the new sheet:

```
A2 ->w3 and CY6
B2 ->G2
C2->AI4
D2->CH5
E2->AE4
G2->DA6
H2->CQ6

A3 ->w8 and CY11
B3 ->G7
C3->AI9
D3->CH10
E3->AE9
G3->DA11
H3->CQ11

and 

A4 ->w13 and CY16
B4 ->G12
C4->AI14
D4->CH15
E4->AE14
G4->DA16
H4->CQ16

again 

A5->w18 and CY21
B5 ->G17
C5->AI19
D5->CH20
E5->AE19
G5->DA21
H5->CQ21
```

and again the same logic for the next rows

I managed to do it for one row but I don't manage to automate and append the result correctly.

I need to use a macro/vba as this process needs to be done 900 times...

Here is my vba code:

```
' Get the last row in the source sheet
lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' Migrate the data row by row
For targetRow = 2 To lastRow
        With targetSheet
        .Cells((targetRow - 1) * 4, 23).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(targetRow, 1).Value ' Migrate column A to target column W3
        .Cells(((targetRow - 1) * 4) + 3, 99).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(targetRow, 1).Value ' Migrate column A to target column CY6
        .Cells(((targetRow - 1) * 4) + 1, 7).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(targetRow, 2).Value ' Migrate column B to target column G2
        .Cells(((targetRow - 1) * 4) + 2, 35).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(targetRow, 3).Value ' Migrate column C to target column AI4
        .Cells(((targetRow - 1) * 4) + 3, 31).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(targetRow, 4).Value ' Migrate column D to target column CH5
        .Cells(((targetRow - 1) * 4) + 2, 31).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(targetRow, 5).Value ' Migrate column E to target column AE4
        .Cells(((targetRow - 1) * 4) + 3, 106).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(targetRow, 7).Value ' Migrate column G to target column DA6
        .Cells(((targetRow - 1) * 4) + 1, 93).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(targetRow, 8).Value ' Migrate column H to target column CQ6
    End With
    Next targetRow
```

kind regards,

Hugo

Comment: I did this for the first row



' Migrate the data
    targetSheet.Range("W3").Value = sourceSheet.Range("A2").Value
    targetSheet.Range("CY6").Value = sourceSheet.Range("A2").Value
    targetSheet.Range("G2").Value = sourceSheet.Range("B2").Value
    targetSheet.Range("AI4").Value = sourceSheet.Range("C2").Value
    targetSheet.Range("CH5").Value = sourceSheet.Range("D2").Value
    targetSheet.Range("AE4").Value = sourceSheet.Range("E2").Value
    targetSheet.Range("DA6").Value = sourceSheet.Range("G2").Value
    targetSheet.Range("CQ6").Value = sourceSheet.Range("H2").Value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim arrMaps, wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, rw As Range, i As Long
    Dim v, arr, lr as Long
    
    'array of cell mappings
    arrMaps = Array("A1>W3", "A1>CY6", "B1>G2", "C1>AI4") 'etc etc
    
    Set wsSrc = Worksheets("source")
    Set wsDest = Worksheets("destination")
    i = 0
    'loop data rows
    lr = wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each rw In wsSrc.Range("A2:H" & lr).Rows
        For Each v In arrMaps   'loop over mappings
            arr = Split(v, ">")
            'note `arr(0)` is *relative* to range `rw`
            wsDest.Range(arr(1)).Offset(5 * i).Value = rw.Range(arr(0)).Value
        Next v
        i = i + 1 'increment destination offset
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I tried your code but I got an error message for this line of code:  
wsDest.Range(arr(1)).offset(5 * i).Value = rw.Range(arr(0)).Value -------it says : Application-defined or object-defined error---- I also adapted the array of cell mappings

Comment: okay, it worked but only for the first row. Id don't know why the loop for the next rows doesn't work

Comment: It worked. Thanks ! It can be closed